# Custom Table Cell display

Tags: swift

[image]

Just wondering what the reason is for the custom table cell not showing the entirety of the text? I have tried remaking the whole custom class and linking everything up but the problem still exists.

Comment: So, what is missing?

Comment: I was wondering why the label didn't show the whole text but only part of it?

Comment: Which label is missing what? I just see Label, Label, Label

Comment: Like in the simulator the third label has the text "welcome" but it only shows we...

Comment: Ah. You might think here are clairvoyants, but there aren't ;-) Have you tried  a clean build (cmd-shift-k)?

Comment: Ahh just tried it didn't work :\ any other recommendations?

Comment: Maybe a problem with your AutoLayout? Check if the labels have 100% width.

Comment: Yeah they do have 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem! I had to replicate the file and then delete the whole TableViewController, probably something bugged with Xcode itself?